# Dynamically compiled project losing resources

Tags: c#, roslyn

I need to compile source code of big project dynamically and output type can be Windows Application or Class Library. 
Code is nicely executed and its possible to make .dll or .exe files, but problem is that, when I'm trying to make .exe file - it's losing resources like project icon. Result file doesn't include assembly information to.

Any way to solve this? (Expected result should be the same, that manual Build function on project file in Visual Studio 2015). 
Thank you!

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
//Locating project file that is WindowsApplication
var project = workspace.OpenProjectAsync(@"C:\RoslynTestProjectExe\RoslynTestProjectExe.csproj").Result;
var metadataReferences = project.MetadataReferences;

// removing all references
foreach (var reference in metadataReferences)
{
  project = project.RemoveMetadataReference(reference);
}

//getting new path of dlls location and adding them to project
var param = CreateParamString();  //my own function that returns list of references
foreach (var par in param)
{
  project = project.AddMetadataReference(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(par));
}

//compiling 
var projectCompilation = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
  var result = projectCompilation.Emit(stream);
  if (result.Success)
  {
   /// Getting result 

   //writing exe file
   using (var file = File.Create(Path.Combine(_buildPath, fileName)))
   {
       stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
       stream.CopyTo(file);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can embed them manually yourself after compilation if you don't mind doing some extra work. For more info see: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7791

Answer (score 2):

We never really designed the workspace API to include all the information you need to emit like this; in particular when you're calling Emit there's an EmitOptions you can pass that includes, amongst other things, resource information. But we don't expose that information since this scenario wasn't hugely considered. We've [done some of the work in the past to enable this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/9890) but ultimately never merged it. You might wish to consider filing a bug so we officially have the request somewhere.

So what can you do? I think there's a few options. You *might* consider not using Roslyn at all but rather modifying the project file and building that with the MSBuild APIs. Unfortunately I don't know what you're ultimately trying to achieve here (it would help if you mentioned it), but there's a lot more than just the compiler invocation that is involved in building a project. Changing references potentially changes other things too.

It'd also be possible, of course, to update MSBuildWorkspace yourself to pass this through. If you were to modify the Roslyn code, you'll see we [implement a series of interfaces named "ICscHostObject#" (where # is a number) and we get passed the information from MSBuild to that](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/e065c1c39642a21615ff5ea6913dd3e3e04ab461/src/Workspaces/Core/Desktop/Workspace/MSBuild/CSharp/CSharpProjectFileLoader.CSharpProjectFile.cs#L755). It looks like we already stash that in the command line arguments, so you might be able to pass that to our command line parser and get the data back you need that way.